# Query array of dict in mongoDB with variable intermediary key

Tags: python, mongodb, list, dictionary

I have the following document:

```
{
  "_id": "xyz",
  "data": {
    "cat": {

    },
    "exec": [
      {
        "22-09-2017 09:12:24": [
          {
            "orderNo": "2345",
            "status": "pending"
          },
          {
            "orderNo": "8907",
            "status": "Approved"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "23-10-2017 10:32:26": [
          {
            "orderNo": "0009",
            "status": "pending"
          },
          {
            "orderNo": "8245",
            "status": "pending"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I query the `exec` list in mongo database with a given `orderNo` when `22-09-2017 09:12:24` is a variable key itself?

I need to have the `_id` as a query field too.

Comment: You mean **_id AND 22-09-2017 09:12:24.orderNo** ??

Comment: Not exactly. The query parameters I have are `_id`, `orderNo`, for me to get the `status` for the corresponding `orderNo`.

Comment: `orderNo` is within `22-09-2017 09:12:24`, how can you access only `orderNo` without it's parent tag?

Comment: @Prgmr can you show the expected result?

Comment: I just need to change the `status` to 'APPROVED' after running an external api. What I have till yet is a series of `for` loops, which finally gives me `db.coll.update({'_id' : k},{"data.exec."+ str(l)+".status": 'APPROVED'})` for the corresponding `orderNo`.